# JQUERY UI theme css not being applied in ASP.NET MVC 4 web project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface, themes, asp.net-mvc-4

I downloaded redmond theme of jquery ui themes. Copied everything under redmond to \content\themes, copied jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js to \scripts, updated jquery to jquery-1.7.2.js and added the following to _Layout.cshtml.
However, the ui doesn't seem changed.

```
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


Here is the structure of the Content folder
Content
   Themes
     base
     redmond
       images
       jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css
    Site.css
Scripts
   jquery-1.7.2.min.js
   jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js
```

Comment: That looks fine. View the source and click on the link to your stylesheet and see if it's 404.

Comment: I pasted the URLs of css file and js files in the browser.All are valid.

Comment: Are the image Urls inside `jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css` pointing to the right place?

Comment: I believe the image Urls are pointing to the right place. I have updated my question. See content folder structure.

Comment: Is your browser caching? (Try Ctrl + F5 a few times to clear the cache.)

Comment: I tried. Still not working. And also I tried asp.net MVC3 + JQuery UI theme. Not working either.

Comment: In firebug, I can open the css file and see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, it is working. I copied some ui controls from index.html that comes from the package to my web page. It worked properly.